# Erasing from a pointer to a vector of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, delete-operator

For the following code:

```
vector<int*> x;
vector<int*>* p;

// say I initiated x with a couple of integers
p  = &x;

//erases the indicie of the given integer
void erase(vector<int*> &x, int n){
  int i = 0;
  while (*(x[i]) != n){
    i++;
  }
  delete x[i];
  x.erase(x.begin() + i);
}
```

If I call the code `erase(*p, 2);` I want to now set `p` to this address of this vector that has been erased ... I'm trying `p = &(*p);` .. but that doesn't work and I get a segmentation fault, any ideas?

Comment: You need to explain it better. It is completely unclear at this point. "i want to now set p to this address of this vector that has been erased" - what is that supposed to mean? No vector is erased in your code and there's no reason to do anything with `p`.

Comment: basically want p to be the address of this new vector, since erase took that vector and removed a certain indicie.

Comment: @JohnSmith, there is no new vector. The old vector is the only vector. It persists through the call to `erase`.

Comment: @JohnSmith - Consider [this program](http://ideone.com/R4xERk) program and its output.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have to do anything. `p` still points to `&x` just as it did before you called `erase()`. Removing an element from a vector doesn't change the address of the vector.

Comment: so after i call erase (*p, 2), p will now be the address of the vector of a shorter vector. ?

Comment: `p` will be unchanged, and will continue to point to `x`. You only have one vector, there is no "shorter vector".